# Get Count from one value in three table linq2sql select?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I just want the apartment complex count along with the other values. Only adding the count breaks the code. The error I get is "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'." I have also tried changing apartCount to an int with no luck. Any help would be appreciated

```
using (var db = new DataClasses2DataContext())
        {
            var zips = (from s in db.ZipCodeServiceAvailabilities
                        join b in db.ZipCodeBoundaries on s.ZipCode equals b.ZipCode
                        join a in db.pdx_apart_views on s.ZipCode equals a.Zip_Code
                        where (s.IsServiced == 1 && b.Ordering % 10 == 0) 
                        orderby b.ZipCode

                        select new
                        {
                            zipCode = b.ZipCode.Trim(),
                            latitude = b.Latitude,
                            longitude = b.Longitude,
                            apartCount = a.Apartment_complex.Count()


                        }).ToArray();
             }
```

Comment: Count from one value is 1.

Comment: What is the type of `Apartment_complex`?

Comment: Are you trying to get the apartment count for each zip code?

Comment: So let me understand this... you want a count of all apartments at each Long/Lat/ZipCode? Equivalent to a Group By zipCode, Latitude, Longitude in SQL?

Comment: I want the number of apartments at each zip code

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It is a string

Comment: OK, then compiler said, that string hasn't `Count` method. What you want to count in string? Number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss `group by` clause in your query.

or you can use corolated sub query in `select` clause. please explain your question more

Comment: I did get it working with a sub query. Took out the "join a" line and made this sub query: apartCount = (from a in db.pdx_apart_views
                                              where a.Zip_Code.Remove(5) == b.ZipCode
                                              select a.Apartment_complex).Count()